# Show that exist a rotation $r$ such that $r(u)=v$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let E the $\mathbb{R}^{3}$  euclidean space,

> Show that, for all $u$ and $v$ unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, there exist a rotation $r$ such that $r(u)=v$

I tried to use the matrix of a rotation but I cannot manage to prove it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you see how does such rotation look like geometrically? Like, what would be the axis?

Comment: Hint: You need the axis-angle representation of a rotation (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis_angle).  You can use the dot product to find the angle and the cross product to find the axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $w\ne0$ we have a reflection map
$$s_w\colon x\mapsto x-\frac{2\langle x,w\rangle}{\langle w,w\rangle}\cdot w.$$
Consider 
$$s_v\circ s_{u-v} $$
(and note that the case $u=v$ is trivial)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Two points on the unit sphere determine a unique great circle on the sphere. Rotations of this circle are restrictions of rotations of the sphere about the polar axis of the sphere that makes this great circle the equator.